# How might cmd's DEL be implemented when parsing its parameters, given that ; is a delimiter?

Tags: c, windows, command-line, args

I'm not that familiar with how it's done in Linux, but I understand that with Windows.. The program can use C's `GetCommandLine()` and see it all, or `argv[]` and the C compiler's libraries will take the output of `GetCommandLine()` and break it into parameters itself and the program can see each parameter.

When an internal program is called. It could be one that takes parameters or one that doesn't.  Echo doesn't.. Maybe ECHO uses C's `GetCommandLine()`?

But let's say the command isn't echo, but one that parses parameters, a command like DEL or DIR. Those commands can use `;` as a delimiter.

```
C:\blah>DEL a;b;c<ENTER>
```

If it were a C program that used `argv[]` then `;` would not be interpreted as a delimiter, only space would.

Is there any known mechanism that it is using to parse the command line, that uses ; as a delimiter?

Do we have the algorithm?  or the library that it uses to parse?

Comment: First, internal commands don't use `GetCommandLine()`, because they run inside `cmd.exe`.  The arguments never leave the command interpreter.  Secondly, for your own program, if you don't like the `argv` rules, then yes, start with `GetCommandLine()`.  The "algorithm" you ask about is string splitting, not the simplest variant, but one that ignores delimiters inside quotes.

Comment: The parsing probably takes place in `cmd.exe` itself, not in a library.  The algorithm for command-line parsing is incredibly complicated, but I believe there is an existing question and answer describing it.  Not sure whether anyone has studied the parsing of `DEL` in particular, but it is probably straightforward.

Comment: [Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737438(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that is far from giving the algorithm

Comment: search "split by delimiter" on this site E.g `[c] split by delimiter`

Comment: @barlop you want to know how it needs to be done in Linux or in Windows?